# Are jammers relate to electronics or electrotechnics , why?

Tags: electronics

Are jammers relate to electronics or electrotechnics , why ?

Please ,tell me the main difference between electronics and electrotechins and **why we can classify jammers as electrotechics or electronics ?**

Indeed i didn`t found this information in Google

Comment: Hi, it's really unclear what this has to do with amateur radio. Also, in English, there's no such word as electrotechics or electrotechincs; you probably mean electrotechnics, but that doesn't really help clarifying your question at all.

Comment: I can't post this as an answer because the question is on hold.  Electrotechnics isn't a word that gets much use in the United States, so I had to look it up.  After searching Google a bit, I found several sites that define electrotechnics (a.k.a. electrotechnology) as the practical application of electricity, which basically describes all of electrical engineering.  Electronic engineering is a subfield of electrical engineering, so I'd say that anything electronic (jammers included) relates to both electronics and electrotechnics.